# Issue with adding multiple connection factories to spring social with spring 3.0.3

Tags: spring, spring-social

I am getting the following exception with my spring social config, if I put more than one connection factory.

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactoryLocator' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/social-config.xml]: Error setting propert
y values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'connectionFactories' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1353)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:574)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:641)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1181)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:584)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:496)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:36)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:481)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:470)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:339)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.start(Scanner.java:275)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:542)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:226)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1061)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:994)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:477)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:623)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.parseCommandLine(Main.java:273)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:81)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'connectionFactories' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:102)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1350)
        ... 47 more
2012-09-25 23:39:19.349:WARN::Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/loginapp,file:/C:/Users/Gaurav/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8081-SpringLoginApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war-_loginapp-any-/webap
p/},C:/Users/Gaurav/.m2/repository/com/myLogin/common/SpringLoginApp/1.0-SNAPSHOT/SpringLoginApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactoryLocator' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/social-config.xml]: Error setting propert
y values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:|PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationExce
ption: Property 'connectionFactories' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1353)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:574)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:641)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1181)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:584)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:496)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:36)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:481)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:470)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:339)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.start(Scanner.java:275)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:542)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:226)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1061)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:994)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:477)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:623)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.parseCommandLine(Main.java:273)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:81)
Caused by:
org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:|PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'connectionFac
tories' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:102)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1350)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:574)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:641)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1181)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:584)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:496)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:36)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:481)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:470)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:339)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.start(Scanner.java:275)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:542)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:226)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1061)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:994)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:477)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:623)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.parseCommandLine(Main.java:273)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:81)
```

my xml file for spring social config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">

```
<bean id="twitterConnectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.social.twitter.connect.TwitterConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg name="consumerKey" value="${twitter.app.consumerKey}" />
    <constructor-arg name="consumerSecret" value="${twitter.app.consumerSecret}" />
</bean>

<bean id="facebookConnectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg name="clientId" value="${facebook.app.clientId}" />
    <constructor-arg name="clientSecret" value="${facebook.app.clientSecret}" />
</bean>
<bean id="connectionFactoryLocator"
    class="org.springframework.social.connect.support.ConnectionFactoryRegistry">
    <property name="connectionFactories">
        <list>
            <ref bean="twitterConnectionFactory" />
            <ref bean="facebookConnectionFactory" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean name="tokenBasedRememberMeServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailService" />
    <property name="key" value="comsicomsa" />
</bean>
<bean id="usersConnectionRepository"
    class="com.myLogin.security.social.service.SocialUserServiceImpl" />
<bean id="connectionRepository" factory-method="createConnectionRepository"
    factory-bean="usersConnectionRepository" scope="request">
    <constructor-arg value="#{request.userPrincipal.name}" />
    <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false" />
</bean>
```

my POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.myLogin.common</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringLoginApp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>SpringLoginApp Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <spring.version>3.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jcouchdb.version>1.0.1-1</jcouchdb.version>
    <httpclient.version>4.2-alpha1</httpclient.version>
    <svenson.version>1.4.0</svenson.version>
    <junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.16</log4j.version>
    <freemarker.version>2.3.16</freemarker.version>
    <javax-validation.version>1.0.0.GA</javax-validation.version>
    <spring-social.version>1.0.0.RELEASE</spring-social.version>
    <spring-social-twitter.version>1.0.0.RELEASE</spring-social-twitter.version>
    <spring-social-facebook.version>1.0.0.RELEASE</spring-social-facebook.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-openid</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- Spring Social Core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-social.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Social Web (contains login/signup controllers) -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-social.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Social Twitter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-twitter</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-social-twitter.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Social Facebook -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-social-facebook.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate Validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>${freemarker.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.jcouchdb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcouchdb</artifactId>
        <version>${jcouchdb.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Java Mail API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>SpringLoginApp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: can you fix the indenting of xml file please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, per the documentation at http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/overview.html#overview-dependencies, Spring Social is only supported on Spring 3.0.5 or higher. (And when Spring Social 1.1.0 is released, it will only be supported on Spring 3.1 or higher.)

My first recommendation is to try it on *at least* Spring 3.0.5 (and ideally on 3.0.7 or even 3.1.2 if that's an option for you). If that doesn't fix your problem, then I can look into it a bit deeper.

Comment: Hi Craig but with one connection factory the same works the error occurs when I add more than one connection factory to the registry like                                                                                                                                              '<bean id="connectionFactoryLocator"
    class="org.springframework.social.connect.support.ConnectionFactoryRegistry">
    <property name="connectionFactories">
        <list>
            <ref bean="twitterConnectionFactory" />
            <ref bean="facebookConnectionFactory" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>'

Comment: Thanks Craig your recommendation on using Spring 3.0.5 worked cheers .